# How to convert integer into "X"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integer

How to get,

```
1 = X
2 = XX
3 = XXX
```

instead of showing in the index as the number. As the old adage goes, "3 strikes you're out!"

This is in the **index**: `<%= [params[:missed]].flatten.length %>`

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Remove the code which is not needed to help you. It is unnecessary take more time..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
n = 3
'X' * n
# => 'XXX'
```

There's other stuff in there you can clean up like:

```
def save_with_current_level
  5.times do
    self.levels.build
  end

  self.save
end
```

Whenever possible, try and express yourself in as little code as possible. The less there is to read, the more obvious bugs become.

Comment: Thanks @tadman! Where do I put `n = 3
'X' * n`? Do I just make up a method name in the model? How would that work when the integer is 1 or 2? I don't know if your confusing n_days with missed days. I'd only want the integer from missed days to be expressed as X's. I have other integers in there such as levels that I'd want still expressed as an integer. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's just a display thing, so you can do it like `<%= 'X' * [params[:missed]].flatten.length %>` if you want. This is just a pattern to apply as necessary. You could make a helper method if this shows up in more than one place.

Comment: Wow that was a lot simpler then feared. Thank you! I'll condense my code to reflect answer.

Comment: You can build multiple objects at once by passing an array with attribute hashes: `levels.build([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}])` or `levels.build(Array.new(5))`